Is there an encoding in which it's possible to have more characters than bytes?
I wrote code similar to this the other day (pseudo-code):
let numBytes = file.size()
let string = String::reserve(numChars=numBytes)
file.read(&string, encoding='auto')

But then I thought to myself, is there any actual encoding for which the amount of characters I reserved won't be enough? For encodings I'm familiar with, it will always work since numChars <= numBytes, for example:

In ASCII or ISO 8859, each character is represented by one byte
In UTF-32, each character is represented by 4 bytes
In UTF-8, each character uses between 1 and 4 bytes

I can easily come up with an imaginary encoding for which it's not the case, but are there real encodings like this?

In theory yes, but it mostly depends on your definition of what counts as a character encoding.
Such an encoding would need to have at least one character represented as less than 8-bits, though for all strings in an encoding to have this property, all characters need to be at most 7-bits. This does limit such possible encodings to 128 characters (you could make ASCII fit this definition by truncating the undefined high-bit).
While more typically thought of as binary to text, going the other way Base64 could be considered a character encoding which only requires 6 bits per character, thus allowing more characters than bytes.
I would argue packed binary-coded decimal is a character encoding. Since its purpose is to represent a digit specifically in base 10 instead of a raw binary number, that digit could easily be considered a character (similarly, ASCII also has digit characters). Each BCD digit is 4 bits, so we get two characters to a byte.
